# Access parameter value in app component angular2

Tags: angular

I am using a dropdown in appcomponent. when user changes the dropdown it loads page in routeroutlet. when i refresh, page in router gets loaded but dropdown is unselected. How can i set dropdown value in appcomponent

Comment: after refresh you will not able to achieve values

Comment: yes i am not able to access activated route parameter

Comment: in appcomponent.html i have routeroutlet. on change of dropdown i am passing id and calling router.navigate to load page in routeroutlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'contacts-detail',
  ...
})
export class ContactsDetailComponent {

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
   console.log("_route",_route);    
  }
}
```

_route will help you

Comment: I can access productid  using _route in productcomponent. However i am not able to access productid in appcomponent.

Comment: console.log("this._route", this._route.snapshot.url.toString());

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to select the dropdown from component. It gets selected automatically based on the current route. router-link-active class is added to the anchor tag when the current route is active:

Example:

```
<div class="sidetab" id="tab1-tab">
   <a [routerLink]="['Profile','ProfileOverview']">
   <span class="innerSpan"> Overview </span>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="sidetab" id="tab2-tab">
   <a [routerLink]="['Profile','ProfileActivity']">
   <span class="innerSpan"> Activity </span>
   </a>
</div>

// Css goes as

.router-link-active .innerSpan {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```